# where do .on(), .write(), pipe() and other nodejs method originate from?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning nodeJS and I was looking at code regarding streaming data from text. More specifically how to write to streams and piping to a writable stream (if I'm saying that correct). These are the two pieces of code are as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var readable = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt', { encoding: 'utf8', highWaterMark: 16 * 1024 });

var writable = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/greetcopy.txt');

readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
    writable.write(chunk);
});

var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var readable = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt');

var writable = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/greetcopy.txt');

var compressed = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt.gz');

var gzip = zlib.createGzip();

readable.pipe(writable);

readable.pipe(gzip).pipe(compressed);
```

This is a noob question but are the .on(), .write() and .pipe() methods built into Nodejs itself (so it applies to all variables) or is it somehow added on when the variables writable/readable are assigned the functions in the fs module? I'm guessing this applies to other methods I will come across while learning.

Comment: Those are part of the library nodejs provides.

Comment: @zerkms I figured, so they can be applied to any variable created in nodejs granted it's used correctly then?

Comment: "so they can be applied to any variable created in nodejs" - nope. Those methods are not magic, and as any other methods of every other object they defined only where they are defined.

Comment: @DanT29: They are methods provided by Stream objects. See the documentation: `https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable`. `.on` is a bit special, they are provided by EventEmitter objects and all Stream objects inherit from EventEmitter. This is just regular OO and the Stream classes and EventEmitter class can be implemented using pure javascript. Only when you hit low-level hardware access like fs or net do you need to write your node modules in C